# LINQ: How can I Join to child table using data from group join?

Tags: vb.net, linq

I have to expand upon an existing query in one of the applications I'm working on.

Table relationships are as follows:

```
tableName     relationship   tableName2     Join columns 
title         1:1            parcel         p_id:p_id   
title         1:many      transaction    title_no:new_title_no  
transactions  many:1         title          old_title_no:title_no
```

The query is essentially a data loader to reduce the number of round trips to the database.
The existing query looks like this:

```
From title In context.Title
Join parcel In context.Parcel 
On title.p_id Equals parcel.P_Id
Group Join transaction In context.Transaction
On title.title_no Equals transaction.New_Title_No And title.transfer_date Equals transaction.Transfer_Date Into transactions = Group 
Select New TitleSearchResult() With {.Title = title, .Pc_Parcel = parcel, .Transactions = transactions}
```

Which returns a custom data type to store the different values.

The application also maps these values(the Title entity contains unmapped properties to store the data from the other entities) :

```
 For Each result In query
      result.Title.Parcel = result.Parcel
      result.Title.Transactions = result.Transactions.ToList()
 Next
```

I need to return the title associated with each transaction based on old_title_no.
I've tried to break the queries up as follows:

```
Dim query1 = From title In context.Title
             Join parcel In context.Parcel 
             On title.p_id Equals parcel.P_Id
             Select title, parcel
Dim query2 = From title_old In context.Title
             Join trans As Transaction In context.Transaction 
             On title_old.title_no Equals trans.Old_Title_No
             Select trans, title_old
Dim query3 = From b In query1
             Group Join c In query2
             On b.title.title_no Equals c.trans.New_Title_No And b.title.transfer_date Equals c.trans.Transfer_Date
             Into transactions = Group
             Select b.title, b.parcel, transactions
```

Which seems to do the right querying, but doesn't allow me to  create a new TitleSearchResult object like the following (because I can't break out the data from the transaction object):

```
From t In query3.ToList()
Select New TitleSearchResult() With {.Title = t.title, .Pc_Parcel = t.parcel, _
.Transactions = t.transactions.trans, .Old_Titles = t.transactions.title_old}
```

How can I still do the group join on transaction (because I need the IEnumerable returned so that I can use it in another query on the database) and be able to separate the trans and title_old objects?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by `in order to create a list` but since you are grouping, you are getting multiple `Transaction` objects per `b.title`, so do you want to create multiple `TitleSearchResult` objects with the same `Title` and different `Transaction`s?

Comment: @NetMage Sorry, I must have zoned out on that last sentence.  See corrections.  Not quite, I'm looking to create a single TitlesearchResult for each t.title .   Each TitleSearchResult should have a list of transactions, and each transaction should have an old_title associated with it.

Comment: What are they types of `TitleSearchResult.Transactions` and `TitleSearchResults.Old_Titles`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the `TitleSearchResult` has `List` types for `Old_Titles` and `Transactions`, you can do:

```
var ans =  From t In query3.ToList() _
           Select New TitleSearchResult() With {
               .Title = t.title,
               .Pc_Parcel = t.parcel,
               .Transactions = t.transactions.Select(Function(t1) t1.trans).ToList(),
               .Old_Titles = t.transactions.Select(Function(t1) t1.title_old).ToList()
           }
```

Comment: I didn't know how to split the grouped data back apart (most info I found just looped through the grouped data after the fact).  Thanks for taking the time to give me a hand!